# will dagger clear/GC the unreferenced object which has application life scope

Tags: java, android, dagger, onsaveinstancestate

This is the use case. In one Fragment (call it PagerFragment) it has injected a object (call it DI_O) which is annotation @Singleton with constructor injection. when the fragment is attached to a activity it gets the object DI_O instance through dagger.

when the activity is destroyed so does the fragment, will this DI_O be GC-ed?

When implemented this way, noticed that like configuration change or whatever reason os killed the activity (minimize app with 'dont keep activity alive' to simulate), then restored the activity, then the same DI_O get injected through the dagger:

```
Application.getApplicationComponent(activity).inject(this);
```

And this is what is desired since during the activity's session there are some data stored in the DI_O, which is required for the same session when the os restores the activity.

But does it mean the DI_O instance will live forever with the application's life time, which is not desired for here? If the activity is a fresh one `(onCreate() with savedInstance == null passed in as param)`, we do want get a fresh DI_O instance for the new session.

In our particular use case the onSaveInstanceState() does not help since the data stored in the DI_O is from 3rd party sdk and not serializable, especially they are stream like it only gets through the api next(), after the next() call there is no way to get the same data again from the stream. It does not have something like an ID for the same data could be re-retrieved. And for some session it could be over one meg.

what is the better way to store the data same as the onSaveInstanceState() does, but also will be cleared when the activity/fragment is truly destroyed (isFinishing() == true).

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject
    DI_O mDio;  

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        super.onAttach(activity);
        Application.getApplicationComponent(activity).inject(this); 
    }
    ........
}

@Singleton
public class DI_O extends BaseO {

    private Set<Data> mCurrentSeesionData = new HashSet<>();

    @Inject
    public DI_O() {
        super();
    }
    ........
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    ApplicationyModule.class
})

public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(ContentPagerFragment contentPagerFragment);

    ........
}
```

Comment: Android `ViewModel` is the desired scenario you are describing - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html this type of thing can easily be done with some logic, but seeing as their is already a library available, it makes sense to use that.

Comment: @MarkKeen, thanks! The ViewModel is helpful for the configuration change case. but I guess it does not help if the os kills the activity and restores it later (i.e. when app is minimized and os needs resource so killed the app, but user could get it back from the most recent activity list), in that case the saveInstance is not null, but the previous ViewModel is not there anymore.

Comment: if the user starts an app from "Recent Apps" and the OS has destroyed the `Activity` or process, then it will be reloaded (recent apps are merely a screenshot or your app in its last visual state - it has no relation to its state in memory - ever wondered why recent apps stay on reboot - its just an image!).  In this case you'll need to think about persisting values by using `SharedPreferences` or some other persistence medium. These can be written in `onDestroy()` and read in `onCreate()`. Write the values when the app is closing i.e. `isChangingConfigurations()` is false in `onDestroy()`

Comment: the question is about for the case cant get help from onSaveInstanceState, or persisting the data (ideally the sdk providing the data we are using should build the mechanism for supporting that).    regarding the ViewModel the https://www.techyourchance.com/android-viewmodel-architecture-component-harmful/  has a few good points.